# How do I parse this JSON string using GSON in servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, gson

How can I parse this JSON string to create collection object in servlet

```
{"title":["1","2"],"amount":["1","3"]}
```

inner class in my servlet

```
public class Data {
    private List<String> title;
    private List<String> amount;
  //getters and setters
}
```

parsing json

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String param=request.getParameter("info");
Data data = gson.fromJson(param, Data.class);
List<String> a=data.getTitle();
 if(a==null){p("a null");}else{p("a not null");} //here a is null, prints "a null"
```

here is the jsfiddle of how I am creating the json string http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/XDNLp/

client side in form submit function

```
var dataString=JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: {"info":JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject())},
    success: function(data){

    }
  });
```

This is what I have till now. am I on correct way? what next should I do to System.print them?

Comment: Yes you're on right way. I can't understand what is the problem?

Comment: Hmm toString() method in Data override and print...

Comment: problem is when I call getter method and System.print, null pointer exception occures

Comment: Can you add all code. (also the code that produce exception)

Comment: where is perkAmount? I don't see it...

Comment: Also are you passing the JSON as a url parameter? can you show the curl command that you send on the client side?

Comment: sorry copied from different program

Comment: Also is interesting what is in param String

Comment: look at the jsfiddle to see how I am creating json string

Comment: why don't you print the param on the server so you can see what you actually got, not what you're doing on the client side.

Comment: editd question with everything now

Comment: There is no getMethod =) And you didn't print real value of param

Comment: param is the string that client send after submitting the form {"title":["1","2"],"amount":["1","3"]}

Comment: there is get method in Data class, I havnt written here

Comment: have you actually verified that the json received on the server is exactly that? Because the GSON code you've provided is correct, which to me says that the JSON you're server gets in the param is not what you think.

Comment: yes when I do System.print param it shows the same string, that is  {"title":["1","2"],"amount":["1","3"]}

Comment: what should be done now? getTitle returns null

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44389185/1404798). You can get simple example with this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I am unable to solve something, I write the smallest possible program to verify my understanding is correct. In your case, I came up with this:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
public class GsonTest {

public static class Data {
    private List<String> title;
    public List<String> getTitle() {return title;}
    public Data() {}
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Data data = gson.fromJson("{\"title\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}", Data.class);
    System.out.println(data.getTitle());
} 
}
```

Compiled, and ran, and it outputs:

```
["1", "2"]
```

So I still believe that the input that the servlet receives, is not correct (or you have not provided an accurate description of your existing code). Please compare the example above, against your real code.

Comment: Yes this example works, thanks for this I will try to make my code by comparing it with this. thanks

Comment: this example really helped me, as I was working on json first time, I was looking for complete general solution, searched on SO but those questions were specific to their issues, anyways thanks +1 and and aceepting this

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public class Data {
    private ArrayList<String> title;
    private ArrayList<String> amount;
  //getters and setters
}
```

List is a abstract class (So GSON doesn't know how to create it)

Comment: You can't use abstract class as `List` in object `Data`. Because GSON can't get instance of abstract class, it is impossible.

Comment: but now I have ArrayList<String>

Comment: Can you write getter for title? And maybe you have constructor?

Comment: this is my getter method in Data 
public ArrayList<String> getTitle() { return title; }
, No constructor in Data

Comment: this is my setter method 
public void setTitle(ArrayList<String> title) { this.title = title; }
form field names has to be same as the variables in setter method?