# validate JSON string if the value of parameter is string or an array

Tags: java, json, servlets, gson

this is JSON string 1

```
{"title":["1","2"], "amount":["1","2"]}
```

this is JSON string 2

```
{"title":"", "amount":""}
```

string 1 is created when I enter values in form and string 2 is created when I dont,
I want to know if the string is in format 1 that is title is an array ["1", "2"] or format 2 that is title is just a string "" on the server side in a servlet, before I parse it. is there any way of doing so?

this is my previous question, 
[How do I parse this JSON string using GSON in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648273/how-do-i-parse-this-json-string-using-gson-in-servlet/13648576#comment18727247_13648576)

which is solved but as you can see there i have class Data which has instance variables of type ArrayList, so when I parse it with this line

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(param, Data.class);
```

it throws exception

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 24
```

because as I have declared ArrayList, it expects array only in json to parse it without any exceptions....but when I dont enter values in my form it doesnt create json string as

```
{"title":[], "amount":[]}
```

rather it creates like this

```
{"title":'', "amount":''}
```

which has string as value, which causes parsing to throw exception

Comment: `typeof elm == 'string'` vs. `elm instanceof Array`

Comment: @inhan can you please tell me in one or two line about that, write it in answer

Comment: If you want a solution for Java, don't tag your question as JavaScript... I don't see it having anything to do with JS.

Comment: i thought it has javascript array, so added javascript tag too

Comment: My solution was javascript based, having seen your **Javascript** tag. So I deleted my answer below. For the same reason ignore my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) it allows you to parse JSON server side.

It goes something like this:

```
 String jsonString = request.getParameter("jsonParemeter");
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Map fromJsonMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);

 Object object = fromJsonMap.get("title");
 if (object instanceof Collection) {
  // then is it's your array
 }
 else {
   // it's not
 }
```

If, for example, I run the following example code:

```
String json1 = "{\"title\":[\"1\",\"2\"], \"amount\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}";
String json2 = "{\"title\":\"\", \"amount\":\"\"}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap map = gson.fromJson(json1, HashMap.class);
HashMap map2 = gson.fromJson(json2, HashMap.class);

System.out.println(map);
System.out.println(map2);

System.out.println(map.get("amount").getClass());
System.out.println(map2.get("amount").getClass());
```

I get as output:

```
{amount=[1, 2], title=[1, 2]}
{amount=, title=}
class java.util.ArrayList
class java.lang.String
```

If I understood you correctly I think it suits you 100%

**UPDATE**

Since you are trying to deserialize your JSON string directly to a Data object, if you want to keep doing that direct deserialization you have to use a [custom deserialization mechanism](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

Comment: I want to check it before I parse it. because if its of String 2 as above then fromJson going to thorow exception

Comment: @vikasdevde: fromJson won't throw an exception for string 1 will return you arrays, and for string 2 will return you strings (empty strings). Check my edited answer with example code

Comment: no, you dont know whats the condition here, and yes you are correct from your side, thanks for your time. +1

Comment: @vikasdevde: if there are other conditions that should be taken into consideration I suggest you to edit your question in order to be more specific so I or any stack overflow member can help you correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem as well and this is how I got around it

In your Data object have

```
public class Data {
    // This is a generic object whose type is determined when used by GSON
    private Object title;

    // get the type of object and return as string
    public String getTitleObjType() {
            String objType = title.getClass().toString();
        return objType;
    }

    // used if the object is an ArrayList, convert into an ArrayList<Object>
    public ArrayList<String> getTitleArrayList() {
        // Turn the Object into an arraylist
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // This is to counter the fact that the cast is not type safe
        ArrayList<String> titleArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) title;
        return titleArrayList;
    }

    // used if the object is not an array
    public String getTitleStr() {
            return title.toString();
    }
}
```

When GSON builds the object it will create and each of these to be either a String or an ArrayList

Then when you want to use the objects, test to see what they are

```
ArrayList<String> titleValArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String titleValStr = "";

if(getTitleObjType.equals("class java.util.ArrayList")) {
         titleValArrayList = getTitleArrayList();
         //do whatever you like
}
else if(getTitleObjType.equals("class java.util.String")) {
         titleValStr = getsTitleStr();
         //do whatever you like
}
```