# conversion of java string to json object

Tags: java, json

I have json object named 'jo' in the below code.I convert this json object to java string to return this json object as response.Then how i convert this string back to json object in the required format.Please help me.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
<%
    JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject cellobj = null; //new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    String country=request.getParameter("count");  
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:
        3306/test","root","root");  
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from state 
        where countryid='"+country+"'");  
            while(rs.next()){
                cellobj = new JSONObject();
                cellobj.put("id", rs.getString(1));
                cellobj.put("name", rs.getString(3));
                cellarray.add(cellobj);
            }  
            jo.put("arrayName",cellarray);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jo.toString());
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java?rq=1.

Comment: jo = (JSONObject) jo;  ?

Comment: Just an off-topic note: scriptlets were already a maintenance nightmare 10 years ago; I would really invest time into learning how to use servlets & JSPs together to get clean, maintaintable code and NO java code in your JSPs.

Comment: Please see this link, it may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44389185/1404798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions seems a bit messy + formating of your code is messy too. But as i understood you, in order to convert String back to JSONObject you can do

```
String someString= getResponseFromServer();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(someString);
// and then do with jsonObject variable whatever you desire
```

Also as people sugested you can use java libraries such as [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [JSONLib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) etc

Answer (score 0):

use Code:

```
String returnString = jo.toString();
```

and send as response.

Comment: I wan't to convert this string back to json object.Give me the code for that.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(returnString);

Answer (score 0):

You can use various libraries for this task - i recommend using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You can find good tutorials on their site too, [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

I would use a custom object, not a simple JSONObject - you can deserialize and store your objects this way easily.

Answer (score 0):

use `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("String");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// String to Json Object
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringResponse);

// JsonObject to String
String string = jsonObject.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are receiving response , you can use the following code :

```
 JSONObject json= new JSONObject ( responseString );
```

Then you can process the same as `Json` object .

Like   `String id=json.put("id");`

Answer (score 0):

It is just a suggestion, I also faces like this issue.

Finally, I tried with [GSON](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gson23/files/gson-2.3.jar/download) library. GSON is directly convert your JSONString to java class object.

Example:

```
String jsonString = {"phoneNumber": "8888888888"}
```

create a new class:

```
class Phone {

@SerializedName("phoneNumber")
private String phoneNumebr;


public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumebr) {
this.phoneNumebr = phoneNumebr;
}

public String getPhoneNumebr(){
return phoneNumber;
}

}
```

// in java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Phone phone = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Phone.class);

System.out.println(" Phone number is "+phone.getPhoneNumebr());
```