# Java convert a Json string to an array

Tags: java, android, json

I have a Json String and I am trying to convert it to an array in Java.

```
public void DisplaySubjects(String subjects)
     {
         JSONObject jsonResponse;
         jsonResponse = new JSONObject(subjects));
```

Thats as far as I get.I'm not even sure if I have to create a object first.

What I will need to do eventuallay is attach it to a ArrayAdapter in an android app.

Thanks

Comment: Relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> jsonStringToArray(String jsonString) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
    }

    return stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
new JSONArray(jsonString)
```

or if it is a property:

```
jsonObject.getJSONArray(propertyName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make JSON object first.

For example,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
```

jsonObject may contains other JSON Objects or JSON array.

How to convert the JSON depends on the String.

There is a complete example with some explanation about JSON String to JSON array can be found at http://www.hemelix.com/JSONHandling.