# Is there a way to overload JSONArray to behave like a regular List in a loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm curious if there's a syntactic way to extend JSONArray such that I can then use it in a for(:) loop as I can a List.

So, instead of having to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i< myJsonArray.length(); i++){
    myJsonArray.getString(i);
}
```

I would like to do

```
for(String s : myJsonArray);
```

I realize that I need to make sure that in the above example the object in the array is indeed a String, but given that JSONArrays can only handle a few types that shouldn't be problem.

Comment: I don't think so without using libraries.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527214/java-convert-a-json-string-to-an-array

Comment: [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject) though this is for JSONObject and requires org.json.simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a slight adjustment to the desired syntax:

```
for(String s : iterable(myJsonArray))
```

Then write the `iterable` method something like so:

```
public static Iterable<String> iterable(final JSONArray array) {
   return new Iterable<String> {
       Iterator<String> iterator() {
          return new Iterator<String> {
             int i = 0;

             boolean hasNext(){
                return i < array.length();
             }

             String next(){
                return array.getString(i++);
             }

             void remove(){
                throw new RuntimeException(); //implement if you need it
             }
          }
       }
   };
}
```

> I realize that I need to make sure that in the above example the object in the array is indeed a String

Well not really as if it isn't a `String`, it will be [coerced to a `String`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString(int))  anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the enhanced for loop. [ref](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/enhanced-for-loops.html)

I believe the collection needs to implement [Iterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Iterable.html) to get that functionality. (or you need an `Iterable`)
This is how you would do it, [use enhanced for loop with your class](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).

[JsonArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) does not; so no you can't :-)

Comment: I see... oh well. Thanks though!