# Is there any tool to generate a String from a JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

My doubt is if there is any tool on-line or not to generate a string from a JSON. For example, I have this JSON:

```
  {
    "my_json": [
      {
        "number": 20,
        "name": "androider",
      },
      {
        "id": 3432,
        "name": "other_name",
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I want to declare a String in my code with this values, so I have to write many quotation marks to have my JSON in a String acceptable format.

So I want to know if thre is some tool to generate this String?

Comment: String json = "[
      {
        "number": 20,
        "name": "androider",
      },
      {
        "id": 3432,
        "name": "other_name",
      }
    ]"

Comment: Google for JSON parsers in Java .

Comment: JSON has a fixed set of keys and values. Your sample above, does not. I suppose this is what you meant by "Json-like", but I'd like confirmation before I answer.

Comment: You need to tell us what you are trying to achieve here. Its very difficult to understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list

Comment: I want to write this JSON like a string to test my project. Currently I don't get the JSON by any request.

Comment: I've improved the question. See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Some good choices are:

- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
- [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

They have built in methods to do just whatever you need to do in an efficient way...

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite tell what you want from your original question, but I assume you are trying to output a Java String that contains some JSON that you have generated.

You should use JSONObject and JSONArray to accomplish this.

To create this JSON:

```
{
    "my_json": [
      {
        "number": 20,
        "name": "androider",
      },
      {
        "id": 3432,
        "name": "other_name",
      }
    ]
}
```

You should use this code:

```
JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
a.put("number", 20);
a.put("name", "androider");

JSONObject b = new JSONObject();
b.put("id", 3432);
b.put("name", "other_name");

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(a);
array.put(b);

JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
root.put("my_json", array);

// convert the root object to a string with 4 spaces of indentation
String json = root.toString(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

As told by Angel, Jackson and Gson are two cool libs. 
Gson is very easy to use while Jackson has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try here, Go through the answers mentioned below
[How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java)

in short,

```
Using org.json library:

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
```

Here put your own string.

Edit:
Try here,
http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/
Create a Json object,
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
Put your data using...
    josnobj.put()

Comment: Pretty simple dude, follow this link, read for just 5 mini, you will get the thing in one shot.                        http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/