# Android: put NameValuePair data in JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am trying to put NameValuePairdata to JSONObject. The NameValuePairdata has name as String and Value as JSONArray. Now when I tried to put this NameValuePairdata in a JSONObject, the jsonobject converts the JSONArray value to strings.

Please check below code for more details:

constructing NameValuePair:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));      

    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    if(arrBean != null && arrBean.size() > 0) {
        for (Bean bean : arrBean) {
            JSONObject idsJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                idsJsonObject.put("min", bean.getMin());
                idsJsonObject.put("m1", bean.getMin());
                idsJsonObject.put("sec", bean.getSec());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            arr.put(idsJsonObject);
        }
    }
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("records", arr.toString()));
```

Constructing JSONObject to be send to HttpPost:

```
JSONObject JSONObjectData = new JSONObject();

    for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : nameValuePairs) {
        try {
            JSONObjectData.put(nameValuePair.getName(), nameValuePair.getValue());
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
```

As shown above the JSONObjectData results into the following:

```
{"id":"1","records":"[{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"},{\"min\":\"610\",\"m1\":\"10\",\"sec\":\"\"}]"}
```

You can see, it automatically appends **\"value\"** inside the array values. E.x. \"min\",\"m1\" etc...

Any body has any idea how to avoid appending these **\"value\"**.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192891/conversion-from-string-to-json-object-android

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142238/add-jsonarray-to-jsonobject

Comment: Did you try to find out what nameValuePair.getName() and nameValuePair.getValue() return? Please share this information. Try to Log these values.

Comment: nameValuePair.getName() and nameValuePair.getValue() return proper strings that I constructed initially. At the time of JSONObject.put(), the values get changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `nameValuePair.getName()` and `nameValuePair.getValue()` return strings, so they are added to your json as strings. You should pass a `JSONArray` object as a second parameter in `JSONObjectData.put()`.

As `BasicNameValuePair` accept only string values, try to use `HashMap<String, Object>` instead or recreate the `JSONArray` from its String representation.

Comment: Hi Alexander, to recreate the JSONArray from its String representation, should i replace the **\"** with **"** or is there any other way to recreate. please comment. Thanks.

Comment: The quotes are added when you serialize a JSONObject with String values into it. So `new JSONArray(nameValuePair.getValue())` should work.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I tried `new JSONArray(nameValuePair.getValue())` and it's working fine.