# How to receive JSON in server side i am receiving it as string instead

Tags: json, parsing

I am doing a project in android,from the client i need to send data as json which is working perfect,on the server side am using j2ee where am receiving the result as string,how can i get the result as json or how can i convert it in to json on server side for storing it in db.Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you simply convert the received string to a JSON object?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192891/conversion-from-string-to-json-object-android

Comment: Understand that JSON _is_ a string. I understand that what you want is for your recieving code to automatically get the deserialized structure, but it's  important to understand that it's only JSON when it is a string. You're sending JSON, you're receiving JSON. Deserialize it.

Comment: Thanks.. i got the answer @Daenarys Once again thanks for your valuable time..

Answer (score 0):

You can use :   JSONArray jsonLinkArray = new JSONArray();

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/Gson gson = new Gson();
String messages = gson.toJson(messagesData);
out.println("{\"Messages\":"+messages+"}");

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are sending the payload you might not have set the "content-type": "application/json"
This basically informs that the incoming payload is of json type. By default the server accepts the payload as string.

You can use :-

```
const data = typeof req.body  === "string" ? JSON.parse(req.body) : req.body;
```

in your code else, and parse the string payload to json.