# Android How to read Gson object in android?

Tags: android

I have my response

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "body": {
    "canCreate": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 76,
    "response": [
      {
        "blog_id": 182,
        "title": "Test Blog",
        "body": "<p>dSsadasddaasd<\/p>\r\n<p><img src=\"\/seapidev\/public\/album_photo\/7c\/04\/0478_3c26.png?c=440c\" alt=\"\"><\/p>",
        "owner_type": "user",
        "owner_id": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "creation_date": "2015-04-22 07:16:28",
        "modified_date": "2015-04-22 07:16:28",
        "view_count": 3,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "search": 1,
        "draft": 0,
        "category_title": "Arts & Culture",
        "url": "http:\/\/dev1.bigsteptech.in\/seapidev\/blogs\/1\/182\/test-blog",
        "owner_url": "http:\/\/dev1.bigsteptech.in\/seapidev\/profile\/admin",
        "owner_image": "http:\/\/dev1.bigsteptech.in\/seapidev\/public\/user\/69\/04\/0465_82ca.png?c=b4e4",
        "owner_title": "SocialEngineAddOns Admin",
        "allow_to_view": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to convert it in Gson and then read it, how can I replicate this file structure in my project??

Can you please help me as I am new to android.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: please make a good research before ask questions, there has a lot of web pages that can help you. Your response is JSON so you can just get the string and convert it in to JSON object or if you want more just follow links [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192891/conversion-from-string-to-json-object-android)   [link] (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java class that is the Java equivalent of the JSON you could use a site like: json2pojo (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to do this for you.

Then to convert the JSON to the Java object you can do the following:

```
Gson = new Gson();
Object obj = (Object) gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
```

Where Object is your custom object.

Comment: {
  "status_code": 200,
"body": {
    "canCreate": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 76,
    "response": [
      {
        "blog_id": 182,
        "title": "Test Blog",
        "owner_image": "http:\/\/dev1.bigsteptech.in\/seapidev\/public\/user\/69\/04\/0465_82ca.png?c=b4e4",
        "owner_title": "SocialEngineAddOns Admin",
      }
    ]    I want to read the status_code , response inside body, how can I do this. Please help me here. Thanks

Comment: Please specify the question. You just want the status code?

Comment: Thanks for this it is amazing and solved my problem. I have one other issue also, I want to generate a form in android according to my Json Data, can you please help me how can I do this ??

Comment: @user3256822 Glad I could help! I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer. If you have another question you can start a chat and I'll be willing to help you out!

Comment: Thanks you so much for such a nice support Tim, I really appreciate it. StackOverflow is just like a second life for developers, you guys are really good, thanks again for your support. I want ask one question. I am having a json response and I want to create a form according to this json response with some fields like EditText, Select Box type and so on, can you please help me out here, that how can I generate the form like this in android. Is there any way to do this in android. Please help me here. Thanks you so much in advance. :) :)

Comment: Can you please  give me just an idea about how to implement this or can give some references so that I can continue with them and can solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: In Volley Post Request, I want to send post parameters with it. I know about the  protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("user",userAccount.getUsername());
params.put("pass",userAccount.getPassword());
params.put("comment", Uri.encode(comment));
params.put("comment_post_ID",String.valueOf(postId));
params.put("blogId",String.valueOf(blogId));
 
return params;
}

Comment: But with this we can send only the string parameters, how can I send the integer values also, with this. Can you please tell me.

Comment: What about converting the int to a string temporarily? Like "int".

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate all the classes you need

Comment: Thanks for this it is amazing and solved my problem. I have one other issue also, I want to generate a form in android according to my Json Data, can you please help me how can I do this ??