# How to Print "JSON" object

Tags: android, json

```
{"result":[{"heading":"The City School","text":"Established in 1978"}]}
```

please help printing this type to `json` format?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18192996/5519005

Comment: This is already a valid JSON string. Are you having any issue with parsing this JSON string?

Comment: What you want to print? Where you want to print? Be specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conversion from string to json object android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192891/conversion-from-string-to-json-object-android)

Answer (score 2):

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for pretty-printting.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(uglyJSONString);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
String jsonStr = "{'result':[{'heading':'The City School','text':'Established in 1978'}]}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String headingVal=jsonObj.getDouble("heading");
    String textVal=jsonObj.getDouble("text");
    System.out.println("Heading --"+headingVal);
    System.out.println("Text--"+textVal);                           
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```