# Android Studio can't find an array in a JSON string even though it exists

Tags: java, android

I have the following JSON string:

```
 private String jsonString = "{\"response\":{\"status\":\"ok\",\"userTier\":\"developer\",\"total\":12,\"startIndex\":1,\"pageSize\":10,\"currentPage\":1,\"pages\":2,\"results\":[{\"id\":\"technology/apple\",\"type\":\"keyword\",\"sectionId\":\"technology\",\"sectionName\":\"Technology\",\"webTitle\":\"Apple\",\"webUrl\":\"https://www.theguardian.com/technology/apple\",\"apiUrl\":\"https://content.guardianapis.com/technology/apple\",\"references\":[{\"id\":\"reuters-stock-ric/AAPL.O\",\"type\":\"reuters-stock-ric\"}]}]}}";
```

and it has a JSON array called "results" `"results":[{"id":"technology/apple","type":"keyword"`...

I use the following code to extract the array and then get data from it:

```
  try {
        // build up a list of News objects with the corresponding data.
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(newsJSON);

        // Extract the JSONArray  called "results",
        // which represents a list of data for every news article
        JSONArray resultsArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("results");
```

However android Studio gives me the following error message:

```
E/MainActivity: Problem parsing the News JSON results
org.json.JSONException: No value for results
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:400)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:595)
    at com.example.readjson.MainActivity.extractFeatureFromJson(MainActivity.java:68)
    at com.example.readjson.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7989)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3485)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2045)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because array "results" is in key "response", you need to get from it. Try this..

```
JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray resultsArray = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONArray("results");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the escape characters in the string `\`

Check out [conversion-from-string-to-json-object-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192891/conversion-from-string-to-json-object-android) It has few answered to your problem, choose one that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `JSONObject` with the id `response` and then the `results` from within it.
So something like this:

```
JSONArray resultsArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONObject("response").optJSONArray("results");
```