# Convert String to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, string

I am trying to convert a String to a JSON in Java. I tried Gson and JSONObject.toJson but they are not helping me .

```
 String str = "{"rahul":"reddy"}";
```

This is my string , I want this to be converted into a JSON.Can anyone please help me .

Comment: An example of what you tried and how it failed would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: You should try escaping the `"`s... `String str = "{\"rahul\":\"reddy\"}";`

Comment: What do mean *converter into a JSON*? A valid JSON string? A JSON object (like `org.json.JSONObject`)?

Comment: Do you want to see an answer without GSON? I can show you with org.json which is the built in library

Comment: Looks like this is similar to the question posted in below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

Comment: add those did not help I have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to parse JSON from a string to an object, firstly you'll need to choose a library. An easy choice is [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

```
// note that I have escaped the inner "
String string = "{\"rahul\":\"reddy\"}";
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(string);
```

To get values back:

```
json.get("rahul"); // --> "reddy"
```