# Value results of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm having problem with string cannot convert to JSONObject.Anyone could help in solving this problem? Thanks and very appreciate for helping.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
if (result==null || result.length()==0){
            // no result:
            return;
}

//clear the list
moviesList.clear();

try {
    //turn the result into a JSON object
    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject("results");

            // get the JSON array named "results"
    JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray(result);

    // Iterate over the JSON array: 
    for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
        // the JSON object in position i 
        JSONObject messageObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // get the primitive values in the object
        String title = messageObject.getString("title");
        String details = messageObject.getString("synopsis");

        //put into the list:
            Movie movie = new Movie(title, details, null,null);
        moviesList.add(movie);
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //refresh listView:
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

result has value

the error is in the following line :

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject("results");
```

Comment: new JSONObject("results") ? May be should be new JSONObject(result);

Comment: i've tried tha, it gives the following error:
org.json.JSONException: No value for

Answer (score 1):

```
    String obj=JSONObject.quote(YourData);
    JSONArray lArray=new JSONArray(obj);

    // or simply  Delete the prefix 'results'  from your php Code
    // $res2=array("results"=>$response);
    // and you will retrive directelly your JsonArray like 

    JSONArray lArray=new JSONArray(YouData);
```

Comment: this is not working.... now the value is the long string of result and similar to previous: org.json.JSONException: Value {...<result string which is too long ...> }}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

- That's because your format for `JSONObject` is wrong. See
  [How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java)
  . Just `"results"` is not a `JSON`. Try and have something like:

  `{"result":"blahblah"}`
- Or by mistake you have included double quotes in the `result` while
  writing

  `JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject("results");`

  As `result` is already a string, try replacing the line with:

  `JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(results);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just mixed up these two lines, try it this way:

```
//turn the result into a JSON object
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);

// get the JSON array named "results"
JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");
```

This is assuming the JSON response you get from somewhere contains a JSONObject, which in turn contains a JSONArray in 'results'.

Judging by the comments in your code sample, this is the case, it just is a case of a simple mixup due to similar naming.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the JSON string itself begins with [
e.g.

```
[{"hello":"goodbye","name":"bob","age":26}]
```

if it does this means it is not a JSONObject but a JSONArray.
Try changing

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject("results");

        // get the JSON array named "results"
JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray(result);
```

to something like

```
JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray("results");
JSONObject resonseObject = responseArray.toJSONObject(responseArray);
```