# Convert string to json object using java

Tags: java, json

I have a string data and i want to add it to json and retrive it to add it to excel. But its not happening
Please kindly help
this is my code....

> String table =
>   "[{"id":1,"name":"xxx","location":"xx"}{"id":2,"name":"yyy","location":"yy"}{"id":3,"name":"zzz","location":"zz"}]";

```
 JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(table); // json       String
 projectname = jObject.getString("name"); // get the name from data.
 System.out.println(projectname);
```

Comment: That is not a valid String.

Comment: This question is already answered on this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java
Also this is not a valid string as Dennis suggested.

Comment: use POJO with ObjectMapper. that is quite simple and understandable..

Comment: sorry i have made a mistake adding question.. but in my code its proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSONObject and JsonArray for this as shown below

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray somearr = new JSONArray();
                        while (iter.hasnext()) {
                             ClassName someObject=iter.next();
                            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                            jsonobj.put("id", id_from_someObject);;
                            jsonobj.put("name", name_from_someObject);
                            jsonobj.put("name", location_from_someObject);;

                        somearr.put(seatObj);

                        }

mainObj.put("response",somearr);

return mainObj.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and effective way i will tell you using [json.org](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) and [jackson-mapper-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13) first create a class suppose its name is Person

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    //getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", location='" + location + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

create another class suppose mainclass

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    String jsonString ="[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"xxx\",\"location\":\"xx\"},
                                 {\"id\":2,\"name\":\"yyy\",\"location\":\"yy\"},
                                 {\"id\":3,\"name\":\"zzz\",\"location\":\"zz\"}]";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    List<Person> listFromJsonArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for(int i =0 ;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        String firstObjectAsString = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
        Person person = mapper.readValue(mapper.readTree(firstObjectAsString), 
                                                                   Person.class);
        listFromJsonArray.add(person);
    }
    System.out.println(listFromJsonArray);

}
```

Now using the list get the individual Person objects get the individual values using getters and do whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have an error at defining your table string. I'm guessing you need

```
String table = "[{'id':1,'name':'xxx','location':'xx'}{'id':2,'name':'yyy','location':'yy'}{'id':3,'name':'zzz','location':'zz'}]";
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(table);
```

instead of

```
String table = [{"id":1,"name":"xxx","location":"xx"}{"id":2,"name":"yyy","location":"yy"}{"id":3,"name":"zzz","location":"zz"}];
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(table);
```

Comment: i did same thing but its giving an error saying  org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: yes i got, i add string table to JSONArray and then retrieved  and added to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code for parsing json object

```
String table = "{"keyElement" : {"id":1,"name":"xxx","location":"xx"}{"id":2,"name":"yyy","location":"yy"}{"id":3,"name":"zzz","location":"zz"}}";
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(table);
JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("keyElement");    
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("location"));
}
```

Now You can get idea...