# Pass a String parameter as a non-array?

Tags: java

I'm passing a String parameter into a java function I wrote.

When I pass the string parameter the method is accepting my parameter as follows
    **http://mywebsite.com/getCity.php?StateID={"state":"Alabama"}**

I want my method to accept my string parameter as follows 
    **http://mywebsite.com/getCity.php?StateID=Alabama**

How do I get rid of     **{"state":"Alabama"}**?

Hey Guys,

I'm building an android app. My syntax below is definitely java. I'm going to show you where I'm having trouble. I'm having trouble on the first line of the method so to show you the entire method would be silly.

```
    public JSONArray getDetails(String StateID) {

        // this Log.e is showing {"state":"Alabama"}
        // how do I get it to show Alabama?
        Log.e("StateID= " + " = ", StateID); 
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean javascript?  Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Those two examples don't match by removing the part your talking about. Is it you need to swap those out?

Comment: @RaySülzer, why do you say that?

Comment: I'm just assuming because it is a JSON object.  Unless he is serializing a class in java to a string?

Comment: @RaySülzer I replied to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a JSON object there (and it really should be URL encoded if it's going to live on a URL like that).

Treat it like a JSON object and use [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) to decode it.  Deal with the checked exception thrown however you see fit.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(StateID);
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("state"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know Java, but the best method would be to deserialize the string into a Java object that had a state property. See: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Alternatively, you could just do something ugly like this:

`StateID.substring(10, StateID.length - 2)`

Which should trim {"state":"  off the front, and trim "}  off of the back.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java