# How do I access these JSONObjects?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to access JSONObjects in this [Image link to the JSON code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyvWY.jpg)

I am trying to access the "lat" and "lng" as such:

```json
"geometry": {

    "location": {

        "lat": 37.422258,

        "lng": -122.0840678

    }
}
```

I am using Java in this case. I tried using this:

```java
JSONObject dataObj = obj.getJSONObject("location");
lat = dataObj.getString("lat");
lng = dataObj.getString("lng");
```

But I got no result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please edit your question to include the full JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked you to show your full `JSON` because the picture is blurry and it is always good to show the text but here is how you parse the `JSON`

```
JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray results = dataObj.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry");
JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
lat = String.valueOf(location.getDouble("lat"));
lng = String.valueOf(location.getDouble("lng"));
```

Comment: @Taz. insert a JSON in a post ? what do you mean exactly?

Comment: oops sorry that was a typo! Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

37.422258 is not in quotes, so it's interpreted as a double not a string. Try calling [getDouble](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Ah getDouble makes more sense. But I am still receiving that "location" was not found.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a answer from this post.. looks like a duplicate question:

[How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java)

hope it will help you to get some idea....