# how to convert a string[] to json

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

I declared an array as below

```
String[] finalcodes = new String[50] ;
```

and assigning some values to it finally when I print finalcodes it results as below.

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

but my requirement is to get it as a json object

so please suggest me how to convert my string array to JSON Object.

Comment: Use a framework like jackson to create json objects.

Comment: Your json object doesn't look valid. Where are the field names?

Comment: this link may be help you in this.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

Comment: eventhough it is not valid I need to build it like this, any suggestions

Comment: Suggestion 1: Don't call it JSON. Don't think like JSON. Create your own.

Comment: JSON is key:value format, what are your keys, what are your values?

Comment: What several commenters are pointing out is that your example output is a JSON array, not a JSON object. I suspect you just have your terms confused. What do you mean by "JSON object"? If you don't mean what the actual JSON specification calls an object, please clarify. If the point is just to be able to parse the JSON in whatever system is receiving the data, then a JSON array is fine.

Comment: Google Gson might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson library also check your json is valid;
http://jackson.codehaus.org/ / http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/