# how to get the result of restful web service with httpClient in json format

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, httpclient

I'm developing an httpclient application that use a `list<OBJECT>` from a RESTful web service in JSON format.

I want to use this result in JSON format.

This is my httpclient application class :

```
public class ClientAbortMethod {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/structure/alldto");

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {

              String data= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


                System.out.println(data);
                // Do not feel like reading the response body
                // Call abort on the request object
                httpget.abort();
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the result of executing this code

```
[{"ids":"#AB","champs":[ {"idChamp":1,"order":1,"type":"FROM"},{"idChamp":2,"order":2,"type":"TO"},{"idChamp":3,"order":3,"type":"TEXT"}]},{"ids":"#AC","champs":[{"idChamp":4,"order":1,"type":"FROM"},{"idChamp":5,"order":2,"type":"TO_MAIL"},{"idChamp":6,"order":3,"type":"TEXT"}]},{"ids":"tt","champs":[]}]
```

This is the restful web service

```
@RequestMapping("/alldto")
public List<StructureNotificationDto> GetALLStructureNotification() {
     return StructureNotif.StructureDTOS();
}
```

How can I get the result of this web service in JSON format or other easy-to-manipulate format?

Comment: I don't understand. `data` contains the response content as a `String` and the response content is JSON. What more do you want? JSON is just text.

Comment: data represent the result of the web service in String format, but i want to use the result of the web service in JSON or List<object> format,

Comment: because the web service return a list<Entity>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library. To add libraries, I suggest a dependency management system, like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). After that, use the following code:

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   List<StructureNotificationDto> list = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<StructureNotificationDto>>() {});
```

Then you can manipulate the data.

Comment: after adding Jackson and using this code , i get this error :

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.onlineproject.domain.StructureNotificationDto]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5427c60c; line: 1, column: 3]

Comment: after  adding Jackson and using this code , i got this error :                                         Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.onlineproject.domain.StructureNotificationDto]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5427c60c; line: 1, column: 3]

Comment: If you don't have final fields, just make sure that you have getter/setters for all methods and a constructor with no arguments (make the constructor private so no one else can you use it). If you have final fields, assign them dummy values in your private constructor. Jackson will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to convert the JSON String into Java Object, so you can manipulate it easily. You can use [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) for that purpose.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java) question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to manually convert the JSON response String to Java object using Jackson, GSON.
Here is the example for converting JSON string to Java Object using [GSON](http://www.javatutorialcorner.com/2013/10/how-to-convert-json-string-to-object.html) and [Jackson](http://www.javatutorialcorner.com/2013/10/how-to-convert-json-to-java-object.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientResponse response = resourse.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
if(response.getStatus() == 200)
    return response.getEntity(String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ConfToggleBO togleObj = mapper.readValue(enitity, ConfToggleBO.class);
```