# Passing a org.json.simpleJSONArray to an Intent in Android as an Extra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, json

I have a problem where I receive `JSONArray`(from the `org.json.simple.JSONArray` library) from an API call and I have to pass this `JSONArray` to a new page/intent while trying to transfer the information in my Android App.

The receive information from the API call, I get a `JSONArray`, which I now convert to a string and pass it to the new `Intent` as an string extra.

On the other side, when I receive the string extra, I am not able to convert it back to a `JSONArray`. Calling `new JSONArray(receivedString)` causes the following error:

```
JSONArray cannot be applied to java.lang.String
```

---

Anyways, I saw this:
[How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java) but it did not help me because the API forces me to use the `json.simple` library:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

Therefore, I can't convert my simple json to a regular JSONArray (from `org.json.JSONArray` since `org.json.*` clashes with `org.json.simple`).

For example, if I use

```
org.json.JSONArray
org.json.JSONObect
```

Instead of the simple library, I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray
```

However, if you don't need to use 'simple' here was the solution that worked found in the link above:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("String");
```

So I can't use `org.json` and I need to find out a way to convert a string that contains `JSONArray` format to a `JSONObject` so I can parse it with the use of `org.json.simple library`.

Comment: What do you mean by _org.json.* clashes with org.json.simple_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have edited the question to more accurately describe my problem.

Comment: `org.json` and `org.json.simple` are two different packages from two different libraries. They just happen to have classes that have the same names. There's no reason to expect either to be convertible to the other.

Comment: Please, provide minimal example of the code and your attempt.

Comment: @jameswoo please paste the json you are trying to process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have to use `org.json.simple.*`, here is the solution to convert java Strings that look like `JSONArrays` into parseable `JSONObject`s

```java
String searchResponseJSON = API.search(term, location);

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject response = null;
try {
    response = (JSONObject) parser.parse(searchResponseJSON);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    System.out.println("Error: could not parse JSON response:");
    System.out.println(searchResponseJSON);
    System.exit(1);
}");
```

I hope this helps anyone out there trying to convert strings into parseable `JSONObjects` with the use of the `org.json.simple` library!

Comment: Your question states that you're trying to parse a String that contains a JSON array, yet you're receiving a `JSONObject` in your answer.

Comment: No, I stated that I received a string, that looks like a JSON Array, could you point to me where I made an error?

Comment: Your question discusses passing a String containing the value of a json array around in an `Intent`. Your answer does not address json arrays at all.