# Converting string to json object using json.simple

Tags: java, json

I am using `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.
I want to convert `string` to Json `object`.

```
String value=request.getParameter("savepos");
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(value);
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: "But no success" doesn't tell us any information about the failure mode. What's the value of `value`? What happens with the code you've tried?

Comment: Is "savepos" properly formatted JSON and !null?

Comment: how to convert from Java object ( Sample s = new Sample()) to JSON string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java/59175182#59175182

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

Comment: Since There are Multiple JSONParser libraries, Library name would be helpful

Comment: how to convert from Java object ( Sample s = new Sample()) to JSON string?

Comment: here json.simple Parser is used, I guess.

Comment: @MenukaIshan You can import json-simple's parser from `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`

Comment: Why are all the examples so limited and incomplete?  No import namespace included, the method seems to require a try-catch block, no example how to transfer back to string...  Thanks for this idea, but it could be so much more helpful if you simply completed the thought...

Answer (score 7):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(value);
```

should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

> Converting String to Json Object by using org.json.simple.JSONObject

```
private static JSONObject createJSONObject(String jsonString){
    JSONObject  jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    JSONParser jsonParser=new  JSONParser();
    if ((jsonString != null) && !(jsonString.isEmpty())) {
        try {
            jsonObject=(JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
        } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the newer `com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple` the code is the following:

```
JsonObject obj = Jsoner.deserialize(responseString, new JsonObject());
```

As documented on the project's [API docs](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/target/apidocs/com/github/cliftonlabs/json_simple/Jsoner.html#deserialize-java.lang.String-com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonObject-)