# How to get the notification endpoint from cloudinary of my own rest controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, cloudinary

I have configured cloudinary in my @service class as "TestUploadService"  to upload image for background removal.

**Sample Code:**

```
cloudinary.api().update("woman", 
  ObjectUtils.asMap(
    "background_removal", "cloudinary_ai",
    "notification_url", "https://dev:8080/cloudinary/status" ));
```

I need to write new rest endpoint as mentioned in notification_url. How to hit this endpoint in a separate rest service?

Comment: This answer here provides an example of a Spring Boot controller that accepts a JSON and parses it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112322/21062

Comment: @Igy Should I process this URL via rest template using postForObject?

Comment: @Igy the endpoint gets a "Whitelabel error message". This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 22 06:59:15 UTC 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: That implies you're calling a URL which isn't mapped to the controller, and also that you don't have a controller mapped to `/error` which handles errors

Comment: @Igy I can able to access the endpoint but now the error shows, Required request body is missing: 400 Bad Request

Comment: And are you sending a request body, or are you saying that Cloudinary didn't send one? I've checked Cloudinary's notifications recently and body should contain a JSON string