# Reading Json file with many json objects

Tags: java, json

I wish to read a json file with contents below in Java recursively. How can I achieve that?

```
{"preview":false,"result":{"TransactionType":"Mobile","TransactionID":"STSVSTFS7SVS3S","TransTime":"20181210171511"}}
{"preview":false,"result":{"TransactionType":"Mobile","TransactionID":"LKSNS6S2S7SVS3S","TransTime":"20181210171511"}}
{"preview":false,"result":{"TransactionType":"Mobile","TransactionID":"TSSKBDGD7SVS3S","TransTime":"20181210171511"}}
```

Here is my Java code  except it only reads the first json

```
import com.brian.db.DBConnector;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


public class ReadJSONData {

    private static final String filePath = "D:\\test\\c2b.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            // read the json file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            //System.out.println(jsonObject);
            Object preview =  jsonObject.get("preview");
            System.out.println("Preview:"+preview);

            JSONObject result = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("result");
            System.out.println("RESULT:"+result);

            String transactionType =  (String) result.get("TransactionType");
            System.out.println("TransactionType:"+transactionType);

            String transid = (String) result.get("TransID");
            System.out.println("TransID:"+transid);

            String transTime =  (String) result.get("TransTime");
            System.out.println("TransTime:"+ transTime);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ParseException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: @NicholasK my java code is now indicated.

Comment: The file as a whole is not valid JSON, instead it contains a sequence of JSON objects. Is there some easy rule to detect the boundaries between the objects? In your example it seems that each object is on a text line of its own.

Comment: @Henry i am stuck at navigating through the json sequences. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: where is the root element in your json? post full json

Comment: @NagaveerGowda thats the whole json and the sequence repeats through the json file

Comment: @bademba the file you posted is neither a valid JSON nor JSON collection. The only way is either parsing each line or reading as a String and then modifying it to be say JsonArray

Comment: I solved this by using a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Just [iterate over the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868528/750510) and [parse each one separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757275/750510):

```
public class ReadJSONData {

    private static final String filePath = "D:\\test\\c2b.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            stream.forEach(line -> {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(line);
                    …
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```