# Value org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: http-get, json

I have the error message:

> error in executing get org.json.JSONException: Value
>   org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@ed9ee8a of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

And the following code:

```
 response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        JSONObject locationObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
        JSONObject locationInfo = locationObj.getJSONObject("item");
        lat = locationInfo.getInt("lat");
        lon = locationInfo.getInt("lon");
```

I don't want to return the string, I want to get the items from the JSON string and use them for a google map.

```
String json = "{\"info\": {" +"\"lat\": " + locationGet.getLat() + ", " +   "\"lon\": " + locationGet.getLon() + "} }";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

See [How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java) (The answer by Mappan, not the accepted answer)