# What is diffrence between get and getJSONObject in class Json in java

Tags: java, android, json

I have JsonFormat :

```
{
    "product": [{
        "description": "my describtion",
        "isStock": "instock",
        "linkArray": [{
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/8e4996-1.jpg"
        }, {
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/19b37f-1.jpg"
        }, {
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/33bc31-1.jpg"
        }, {
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/459e33-1.jpg"
        }, {
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/a18f87-1.jpg"
        }, {
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/c58d16-1.jpg"
        }, {
            "link": "http:\/\/rozinleather.ir\/demo\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/d952f8-2.jpg"
        }]
    }],
    "success": 1
}
```

I can't understand how to get nested JsonObject.
thank you.

Comment: `product` is JSONArray. use loop to get Json object using index

Comment: Read the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a `JSONObject` passing the JSON string as a parameter:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

And then, depending on your needs, you may want to fetch an array, another JSON object or a value of the `JSONObject`:

```
JSONArray productArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("product");
Integer success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
```

You can iterate over a `JSONArray` and get all the elements of the array, and do what you want with each object of the array (extract values, fetch arrays or objects of the element, etc):

```
for (int i = 0; i < productArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject product = productArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String description = product.getString("description");
    ...
}
```

Read more about `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` available methods:

[JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

[JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this

```
try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject("yourJsonString");
            JSONArray products = root.getJSONArray("product");

            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); ++i){
                JSONObject prod = products.getJSONObject(i);

               // now parse product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```