# Java string convert to JSON object for http POST

Tags: java, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to recreate a http Post request to consume a webAPI. I originally created it in C# and got it to work. But the java analogous seems to be giving me a bit of ...

my input string consists of parameters expected by the webapi.

```
       String input = "{" +
                "\"UserID\":xxx," +
                "\"UserPsw\":\"yyy," +
                "\"ApiFunction\":zzz," +
                "\"DppName\":aaaa," +
                "\"DppVersion\":Latest, " +
                "\"ClearData\"ftfdgfdgfdg fdgfdgfd 4354534," +
                "\"ResultType\":JSON \"}";
```

Now I downloaded the JSON-simple jar file from:-
https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/downloads

and imported it in my libraries folder for the java project.

then for my main.java class, I imported the following:-

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

The intention is to convert my 'input' string into a JSON onbject as such:-

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
```

but I am getting an error that says:-

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   constructor JSONObject(java.lang.String)
  location: class org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

what am I doing wrong?

The reason I want to convert it into a JSON object, is because my webapi expects a certain format for a string...

```
{"UserID":xx,"UserPsw":yyy,"ApiFunction":zzz,"DppName":aaaa,"DppVersion":Latest, "ClearData":ftfdgfdgfdg fdgfdgfd 4354534,"ResultType":JSON "}
```

however my java string input is formatted as:-

```
{"UserID":"xx","UserPsw":"yyy","ApiFunction":"zzz","DppName":"aaaa","DppVersion":"Latest", "ClearData":"ftfdgfdgfdg fdgfdgf 4354534","ResultType":"JSON"}
```

which is different than how C# sends it as a class object with quotes only around property names and not around values.

Comment: `{"UserID":xx,"UserPsw":yyy...` is not valid JSON.

Comment: it is not ...as i mentioned... in C#.. it is send as a class object. which formats it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs

http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html

there is no constructor that accepts a `String` as parameter. You may think about converting it to a `Map` which would make it clearer and less error-prone.

```
 HashMap<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
 newMap.put("UserID","xxx");
 //... the rest of your attributes
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(newMap);
```

As proposed by 'Mappan' you could use the JSONParser, as well:

```
try {
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Taken from : [How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobje%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bct-in-java)

Comment: I would like to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

Comment: doesn't allow me to format my string as Mappan points out. tried it.. also, look at charu's answer

Comment: unreported exception org.json.simple.parser.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown... on the second line where JSON object is invoked

Comment: Ok :-) That's an exception, that you need to catch. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118675/discussion-between-matt-and-philo).

Comment: worked for me... except in simple.parser... ParsingException is not the correct class name, rather it should be ParseException.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the hint, edited and corrected.