# String.split for JSON array

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following string and I need to split it to get the two objects inside:

```
[Object{value1="1", value2="2"}, Object{Value1="1", value2="2"}]
```

Comment: [see this for json parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5245881/681929)

Comment: Are you familiar with org.json library? You could use JsonArray to get those two Objects into nice array which then can be iterated.

Comment: Is that a valid JSON string ?

Comment: If that is what is inside the String then NO.

Comment: Hi @vilpe89 I'm not familiar with the library, I only need to be able to insert each value in a List<T>.

Comment: @Thomas actually it was originally with { and not [

Comment: Without defined grammar for this string it is not possible **because it is not JSON**

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
String[] splitTextObject = YOUR_STRING.split(", ");
String object1 = splitTextObject[0];
String object2 = splitTextObject[1];
...
```

But I don't think you actually need to split the string this way in order to achieve getting each object, and instead you should consider parsing your JSON. Perhaps utilise [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: I appreciate your help, your solution only splits until Object{value1="1"

Comment: Yes, your original question didn't include spaces between each value. You could instead try String[] splitTextObject = YOUR_STRING.split("Object"); But this will achieve less than desirable results. You are best off looking into parsing JSON.

Comment: Ok, let me try a more advance solution. I used GsonUtil.getGson().fromJson(string, Formatter.class) but I get a JsonSyntaxException expected GSON Object, found GSON Array

Comment: JsonSyntaxException expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was _BEGIN_ARRAY

Comment: I can't help you from the comments of my original answer. You should consider asking a new question altogether, focused on your GSON/JSON queries

Comment: Done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249123/convert-json-response-into-listt

Comment: The question doesn't have JSON anyway. And, by the way Gson is not an acronym like JSON, so it is not all caps.