# Convert JSON response into List<T>

Tags: java, android, json, list, gson

I am new to GSON. I need to convert the following JSON response into a List.

JSON response:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "data": {
            "ac_id": "000",
            "user_id": "000",
            "title": "AAA"
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "ac_id": "000",
            "user_id": "000",
            "title": "AAA"
        }
    }]
}
```

I have a class to cast data

Account. java

```
public class Account {

     public int ac_id;
     public int user_id;
     public String title;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return "Account{"+
         "ac_id="+ac_id+
         ", user_id="+user_id+
         ", title="+title+'}';

    }

}
```

When I cast the response with my class I get:

```
[Account{ac_id="000", user_id="000", title="AAA"}, Account{ac_id="000", user_id="000", title="AAA"}]
```

Now I need to put these two values into a `List<Account>`.
What do you suggest?

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: think you need TypeToken

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray accounts = data.getJSONArray("data");    
List<Account> accountList = new Gson().fromJson(accounts.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Account>>(){}.getType());
```

If you cannot change your JSON response to remove the inner "data" key, you can use this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
JSONArray accounts = data.getJSONArray("data");  
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject a = accounts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");
  accountList.add(gson.fromJson(a.toString(), Account.class));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work with the nested `"data"` key

Comment: I get and JsonSyntaxException Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: @user3478224 As other users have mentioned, it's because you have a nested data key. You should have: {
        "ac_id": "000",
        "user_id": "000",
        "title": "AAA"
    } instead of {
        "data": {
            "ac_id": "000",
            "user_id": "000",
            "title": "AAA"
        }
    }

Comment: @user3478224 see edit if you cannot change your JSON response

Comment: Thank you so much @EliasN your answer works perfect!

Answer (score 4):

For that you can use Tokens so that gson can understand the custom type...

```
TypeToken<List<Account>> token = new TypeToken<List<Account>>(){};
List<Account > accountList= gson.fromJson(response, token.getType());

for(Account account : accountList) {
      //some code here for looping  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That nested `"data"` key is pointless. If you can fix your JSON you should make this instead.

```
{
    "data": [{
        "ac_id": "000",
        "user_id": "000",
        "title": "AAA"
    }, {
        "ac_id": "000",
        "user_id": "000",
        "title": "AAA"
    }]
}
```

And then this will work.

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray accounts = data.getJSONArray("data");
List<Account> accountList = new Gson()
    .fromJson(accounts.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Account>>(){}.getType());
```

---

Or, again, that first `"data"` isn't really necessary either.
If you can get your JSON just to be the list of Accounts...

```
[{
    "ac_id": "000",
    "user_id": "000",
    "title": "AAA"
}, {
    "ac_id": "000",
    "user_id": "000",
    "title": "AAA"
}]
```

This will work

```
List<Account> accountList = new Gson()
    .fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Account>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: JsonSyntaxException Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: Like I said - It's up to you to fix the actual JSON. Don't just copy the Java code I gave.

Comment: Or you could not use Gson and parse the data yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I can not modify my JSON string, it is working with my all classes with no problem. When I try to convert into an object array is when crashes.

Comment: How can I parse the data?

Comment: Use the built-in `JSONObject` class and start parsing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android Of course, you can do the same in Gson but using the otherwise named [`JsonObject`](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0)

Comment: You can't modify this one API response to not put `"data":` as part of the response?

Comment: I will try using String.replace to remove the parts that  avoid match the form you suggest.

Comment: That's risky... I think 'Elias N' has the updated answer that should work if you can't edit the JSON on the server-side

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to where the JSON was created, i think you should make it like this:

```
{"data":[{"ac_id":"000","user_id":"000","title":"AAA"},{"ac_id":"000","user_id":"000","title":"AAA"}]}
```

then to convert it, just use this code: (where jsonString is the string above)

```
List<Account> accountList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Account>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: JsonSyntaxException Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: did you change the JSON first? if not then you will get that error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6709464/elias-n answer was good, but for me, i think it take too much line of code. I prefer simple way more