# cURL GET request with body in Java

Tags: java, curl

I have the following curl request:

```
curl -X GET http://hostname:4444/grid/api/hub -d '{"configuration":["slotCounts"]}'
```

which returns a JSON object.

How can I make such request and get the response in Java? I tried this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://hostname:4444/grid/api/hub -d '{\"configuration\":[\"slotCounts\"]}'");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

But it returns an exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://hostname:4444/grid/api/hub -d '{"configuration":["slotCounts"]}'
```

Comment: Everything starting with `-d ...` is a command line argument to the cUrl executable.  You'll have to implement in Java whatever `-d` does with the value after it.

Comment: `-d '{"configuration":["slotCounts"]}'` is an Option for curl. You can not add it to an URL object

Comment: -d are the data you want to send if i am right. Read here how you can send data to an URL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, managed to solve it myself.

```
private static class HttpGetWithEntity extends
        HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public final static String METHOD_NAME = "GET";

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
} 

private void getslotsCount() throws IOException,
        URISyntaxException {

    HttpGetWithEntity httpEntity = new HttpGetWithEntity();
    URL slots = new URL("http://hostname:4444/grid/api/hub");

    httpEntity.setURI(pendingRequests.toURI());

    httpEntity
            .setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"configuration\":[\""
                    + PENDING_REQUEST_COUNT + "\"]}",
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getPendingRequests);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));

    // At this point I can just get the response using readLine()
    System.out.println(rd.readLine());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not how sending data in Java works. The -d flag is for the CURL CLI only. In Java you should use a library like Apache HTTP Client:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065/5898512

Then parse the result with JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245881/5898512

Answer (score -1):

As per your exception/error log, it clearly says that the service `http://hostname:4444/grid/api/hub` is receiving bad request(Status code 400).

And i think you need to check the service to which you are hitting and what exactly it accepts. Ex: the service may accept only `application/json` / `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or the parameter to service that expecting but you are not sending that.