# How to embed an Example table values into Json in Scenario Outline in Gherkin

Tags: json, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

```
Scenario Outline: I have an audit type <type>
    When a request is received
    """
    {
              "elements":{  
                 "type":<type>,
                 "id":"sku-1"
              }
    """
    Examples:
        |   type    |
        |   test1   |
        |   test2   |
        |   test3   |
```

How to solve the above problem to replace  with the values given in Examples?

Answer (score 2):

I got it worked with simple change

```
Scenario Outline: I have an audit type <type>
    When a request is received
    """
    {
              "elements":{  
                 "type":'<type>',
                 "id":"sku-1"
              }
    """
    Examples:
        |   type    |
        |   test1   |
        |   test2   |
        |   test3   |
```

Comment: Yes, you just needed to surround `<type>` with `''` . Still it would be better to keep feature files for business behavior and coding for the steps :)

Comment: Some place, some time, there is always a valid use case.

Answer (score 1):

Might be better not to use Doc String for JSON. Instead try this:

```
Scenario Outline: I have an audit type
    When a request is received of "<type>"

    Examples:
      | type  |
      | test1 |
      | test2 |
      | test3 |
```

Sorry, the response in in *Ruby*, not familiar with *Java conversion from String to JSON object or Hashtable*. I did however find this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5245840) that might help to manage handle the JSON:

In Ruby:

```
When(/^a request is received of "([^"]*)"$/) do |type|
  json = eval("{'elements':{'type':'#{type}','id':'sku-1'}}")
end
```

First time this runs, `json` will be: `{'elements':{'type':'test1','id':'sku-1'}}`

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Fintinariu , I got the solution by referring to your solution