# Receiving JSON response within Double quotes

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am receiving data from the server using `Volley`, but the received data is coming within double quotes.

```
"{"Meta Data":{"1. Information":"Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes","2. Symbol":"INSI","3. Last Refreshed":"2017-11-24","4. Output Size":"Full size","5. Time Zone":"US/Eastern"},"Time Series (Daily)":{"2017-11-24"....}"
```

I need to parse this information in order to extract the data but I am unable to convert it into `JSONObject`. I am clueless. 
On using `jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);`
The debugger says `jsonArray` is `NULL`
TIA.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

Comment: or this `JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();`

Comment: I added compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1' to my gradle and JSONParser started appearing in intellisense but then getAsJsonObject is still not recognised. @joao86

Comment: JsonParser is from org.gson library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jyotirmaya ojha, the JSON string that you shared have JSON Object not JSON Array, so the debugger will always say jsonArr is NULL because JSON Object cannot be casted in JSON Array

Please try this instead

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

Comment: I am able to access a particular string by its name key, for eg: jsonObj.getString("Time Series (Daily)"). But How can I access the first Key value pair in this string ie. jsonObj.getString("Time Series (Daily)"). Would be easy to parse once I can get values through indices.