# Parsion JSON String into JSONOBJECT in android

Tags: java, android

This is my `JsonResponse` , and since its not in array i am facing some difficulties , can any one help me out ? in android

```
{
    "errorno": "0",
    "responsemsg": "Login Success.",
    "busid": "1234",
    "returnmobileno": "1234567890"
}
```

Comment: What difficulty your facing?

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245881/9388338

Comment: `i am facing some difficulties` then you need *some* changes obviously.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you very helpful :) lol

Comment: @RishabhShukla, same helphful as your *detailed description of difficulties*. I just tried to show that my answer is quite fair as for your description. And you need to improve description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
try {
    String errorno = response.getString("errorno");
    String responsemsg = response.getString("responsemsg");
    String busid = response.getString("busid");
    String returnmobileno = response.getString("returnmobileno");

    Log.d(TAG, "errorno:" + errorno+" responsemsg:"+responsemsg+" busid:"+busid+" returnmobileno:"+returnmobileno);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
try {
 JSONObject lJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    String errorno = lJsonObject .getString("errorno");
    String responsemsg = lJsonObject .getString("responsemsg");
    String busid = response.lJsonObject ("busid");
    String returnmobileno = lJsonObject .getString("returnmobileno");



} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what here response refers to ?

Comment: your JsonResponse

Comment: can we contact ? if you don't mind rishabh1450@gmail.com

Comment: ask me on kapilparmar100@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
    use  below code to pass your strong 
    serverData = gson.fromJson(response, ServerData.class);


    in build.gradle -> dependencies
    // retrofit, gson
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'



    public class ApiClient {

        public static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://example.com/abc/";
        private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


        public static Retrofit getClient() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(SERVER_BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }
    }



    public interface ApiInterface {


        @POST("appServices/getData.php")
        @FormUrlEncoded
        Call<ResponseBody> getAllDataJSONFromServer(@Field("vcode") String vcode);

    }



    public class ServerData implements Parcelable {
    public static final Creator<ServerData> CREATOR = new Creator<ServerData>() {
        @Override
        public ServerData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ServerData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ServerData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ServerData[size];
        }
    };
    private static final int VERSION = 1;


    @SerializedName("errorno")
    private String errorno;
    @SerializedName(responsemsg)
    private String responsemsg;
    @SerializedName("busid")
    private String busid;
    @SerializedName("returnmobileno")
    private String returnmobileno;

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        if (in.readInt() == VERSION) {
            errorno = in.readString();
            responsemsg = in.readString();
            busid = in.readString();
            returnmobileno = in.readString();
        }
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(VERSION);
        parcel.writeString(errorno);
        parcel.writeString(responsemsg);
        parcel.writeString(busid);
        parcel.writeString(returnmobileno);
    }

     @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getErrorno() {
        return errorno;
    }

    public void setErrorno(String errorno) {
        this.errorno = errorno;
    }

    public String getResponsemsg() {
        return responsemsg;
    }

    public void setResponsemsg(String responsemsg) {
        this.responsemsg = responsemsg;
    }

    public String getBusid() {
        return busid;
    }

    public void setBusid(String busid) {
        this.busid = busid;
    }

    public String getReturnmobileno() {
        return returnmobileno;
    }

    public void setReturnmobileno(String returnmobileno) {
        this.returnmobileno = returnmobileno;
    }
}


    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
                // get and save all data from server
                Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getAllDataJSONFromServer(local_vcode, local_cvcode, pckgName);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> responsebody) {
                        try {
                            String response = responsebody.body().string();
                            serverData = gson.fromJson(response, ServerData.class);   // this will fetch data to model class ServerData

                            if (serverData != null) {

                            // do the rest here...
                             String vcode = serverData.getVcode();
                             Log.e("~~~ vode = ", vcode);
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        try {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }
                    }

                });
```