# Process of Array of Strings in Beanshell preprocessor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a Jmeter (version 4.0) test script where I am using json extractor to fetch an array of strings from the response json using **$..Names** and storing it in a variable **groupOfNames**. The various names are stored like groupOfNames_1, groupOfNames_2, groupOfNames_ALL.

I need to make POST call next with body as

```
{
"name1", "name2", "name3" (--actual values--)
}
```

How can i achieve this using bean shell preprocessor?  **groupOfNames_ALL** gives me all value but like this.... name1, name2, name3 (without quotes surrounding individual names). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: may help full to you [stack answer for Jason conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: This is not the issue i am facing but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so you can add quotation marks around each of names as simply as:

```
vars.put('groupOfNames_ALL',vars.get('groupOfNames_ALL').split(',').collect {"\"$it\""  }.join(', '))
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Add Quotation Marks Around Strings]

Also as a gentle reminder: [JMeter users are encouraged to use JSR223 Test Elements for any form of scripting since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: I have to mark your solution as the right answer as it achieved what i wanted in just a single line. Can you explain what collect and $it is doing  in your solution? Thanks a lot anyways :)

Comment: You're asking for a story while I'm limited to a chapter. It is implicit parameter: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Comment: i googled a bit after i asked you and got a rough idea. i am not familiar with groovy so couldn't get it. Thanks for providing the link. It helps

Comment: @DmitriT thanks for this. have been looking for a couple of hours on how to solve this problem :D

Answer (score 3):

Put the below code in your **BeanShell PreProcessor**:

```
int matchNr = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("groupOfNames_matchNr"));

for(int i = 1; i <= matchNr; i++){
    String Names = vars.get("groupOfNames_" + i);
    if(i == matchNr){
        vars.put("AllNames", vars.get("AllNames") + "\"" + Names + "\"");
    }
    else if(i == 1){
        vars.put("AllNames","\"" + Names + "\", ");
    }
    else{
        vars.put("AllNames", vars.get("AllNames") + "\"" + Names + "\", ");
    }
```

Then use the variable **${AllNames}** in your post as below:

```
{
${AllNames}
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine and it solved my problem. Thanks a ton.