# How can i transform String from URL to JSON?

Tags: java, android

So, basically i have this function:

```
public String ReadingURL(String IncomingURL){
    String prueba = "";
    try{
        URL url = new URL (IncomingURL);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            prueba+=prueba;
        }
        in.close();
        return prueba;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: "+ e.getMessage());
        return "Error";
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

It's supposed to read line by line of an URL and extract the content. 
What this URL is gonna contain is basically a JSON Object but like in plain text, what i need to do is to grab
"prueba" that contains the content of the URL and convert that into an actual JSON Object so i can later send a print command with the contents of that JSON .
I'm new to JSON so be gentle haha

Comment: just use an API that can parse Json from String or stream probably...

Comment: the code inside the loop doesn't read the line from URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert jsonString to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: Sharon, what do you mean is not reading the line?

Comment: @SarcasticHawke he means `prueba+=prueba` which is obviously wrong. it must be `prueba = prueba + line`

Comment: OH omg HAHAHA thanks i didn't notice that until now