# How to convert Array[Byte] to JSONObject in Scala

Tags: gson

I have an Array[Byte]. I am trying to convert it into JSON Object.

I tried using GSON library. I got the String representation of the JSON Object. I am stuck at this point and also not sure if this is the correct way.

```
def getJSONObject(array : Array[Byte]) : JSONObject = {
   val jsonString = new Gson().toJson(array)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert jsonString to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java)