# How do I remove backslashes before quotes from a JSONObject string?

Tags: java, json

### Background

I have a list of strings (records) that are dynamically created by a class. Each record may have different keys (e.g. `favorite_pizza` on first, `favorite_candy` on second).

```java
// Note: These records are dynamically created and not stored
// in this way. This is simply for display purposes.
List<String> records =
    Arrays.asList(
        "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":40,\"favorite_pizza\":\"Cheese\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"Jill\",\"age\":22,\"favorite_candy\":\"Swedish Fish\"}");
```

The list of records is then passed to a separate HTTP request class.

```java
public Response addRecords(List<String> records) {
    ...
}
```

Inside the HTTP request service, I want to build a JSON request body:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 40,
      "favorite_pizza": "Cheese"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jill",
      "age": 22,
      "favorite_candy": "Swedish Fish"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using [org.json.JSONObject](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) to add the `records` key and create the request body:

```java
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

// Add the "records" key
body.put("records", records);

// Create the request body
body.toString();
```

### Issues

When I run my junit test in IntelliJ, the request body contains a backslash before each quote:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"{"records":["{"name":"Bob","age":40,"favorite_pizza":"Cheese"}","{"name":"Jill","age":22,"favorite_candy":"Swedish Fish"}"]}"
Actual   :"{"records":["{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":40,\"favorite_pizza\":\"Cheese\"}","{\"name\":\"Jill\",\"age\":22,\"favorite_candy\":\"Swedish Fish\"}"]}"
```

And when I make the request it fails because the body is not formatted correctly:

```
{
  "records": [
    "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":40,\"favorite_pizza\":\"Cheese\"}",
    "{\"name\":\"Jill\",\"age\":22,\"favorite_candy\":\"Swedish Fish\"}"
  ]
}
```

### Questions

- Why is JSONObject including the backslashes before each quote?
- How do I remove the backslashes?

Comment: I doubt it's JSON which has the backslashes, it's Java or its debugger. Where do you look at it? Did you print it on console?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm seeing the backslashes when I run junit tests IntelliJ.

Comment: @Ryan Brooke Payne I reproduced your issue with the same code using Eclipse and printing to System.out.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I clarified where I am seeing the backslashes—in a junit test in IntelliJ—in my question.

Comment: @DaveNewton See my updated question. I made the request and it fails due to incorrectly formatted JSON.

Comment: I've updated my reply to answer your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a list of string, which is not what you want.

You should instead create a list of objects (Maps)

```
Map<String, Object> m1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
m1.put("name", "Bob");
m1.put("age", 40);
m1.put("favorite_pizza", "Cheese");

LinkedHashMap<String, Object> m2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
m2.put("name", "Jill");
m2.put("age", 22);
m2.put("favorite_candy", "Swedish Fish");
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> records = Arrays.asList(m1,m2);

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

// Add the "records" key
body.put("records", records);
```

This is a quite common mistake (it seems), to try to serialize strings formatted like json objects expecting is the same thing as passing a the object itself.

**UPDATE:**

Or if you have a json serialized object list then ...

```
List<String> recordSource =
    Arrays.asList(
        "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":40,\"favorite_pizza\":\"Cheese\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"Jill\",\"age\":22,\"favorite_candy\":\"Swedish Fish\"}");
List<JSONObject> records =
    recordSource.stream().map(JSONObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

// Add the "records" key
body.put("records", records);
System.out.println(body.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks @minus. Unfortunately, the list of strings is dynamically created and passed to this class—the HTTP request service—so I can't implement your suggestion.

Comment: Then you should parse the string into a Map and then add the map to your list.

Comment: I've updated my question to more closely reflect the context I am dealing with. Could you please update your example based on your latest suggestion ("parse the string into a Map and then add the map to your list")? I'm having trouble visualizing the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your record strings are already valid json you can either

1. Iterate over them, converting them one at a time into a `JSONObject` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java)) and then add the result to a `JSONArray` which you can manipulate if needed.
2. Create the array entirely by hand since it's just comma separated record strings inside square brackets.