# Convert serialized JSON string to JSON object in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have Json String Object as below.

```
"{\"SuccessData\":\"Data fetched successfully\",\"ErrorData\":\"\",\"AppData\":\"[{\\\"uniqe_id\\\":{\\\"appId\\\":4,\\\"agentId\\\":1,\\\"isActive\\\":1\\\"},\\\"pid\\\":2223,\\\"appName\\\":ACMP\\\"},{\\\"uniqe_id\\\":{\\\"appId\\\":5,\\\"agentId\\\":1,\\\"isActive\\\":1\\\"},\\\"pid\\\":2225,\\\"appName\\\":ICMP\\\"}]\"}"
```

I want to convert this string to JSON object using java.

I have already tried,

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

I'm getting an `error` saying,

```
   org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'
```

Comment: Good that you have tried something! Do remember though that we are not clairvoyant, so please tell us whether your try worked, and if not, why not (does it error, are the results in correct, does your computer explode...?) Please [edit] your post with more details, preferably also with sample output and input.

Comment: @Meet Patel what do you want to achieve? if you want to work with tghis structure in the future you better need to deserialize it into POJO class, for example.

Comment: I have just tried running this code with the string above and it seems to work fine for me? I assume you're using the org.json:json library?

Comment: Take a look at gson or jackson library if you are going to be working with JSON a lot. Give you the possibility to convert to and back easily.

Comment: Make sure you are using org.json library not google-json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245881/4007703

Comment: Use JsonUtil.sanitize(JsonString) from com.google.json.JsonSanitizer first than proceed with your steps

Comment: Hi @BenGreen, Yes, I'm using org.json library. And i'm getting an error as described in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
"{\"SuccessData\": \"Data fetched successfully\",
  \"ErrorData\": \"\",
  \"AppData\": \"[{\\\"uniqe_id\\\":{\\\"appId\\\":4,\\\"agentId\\\":1,\\\"isActive\\\":1\\\"},\\\"pid\\\":2223,\\\"appName\\\":ACMP\\\"},{\\\"uniqe_id\\\":{\\\"appId\\\":5,\\\"agentId\\\":1,\\\"isActive\\\":1\\\"},\\\"pid\\\":2225,\\\"appName\\\":ICMP\\\"}]\"
}"
```

The real problem here is that this input is not valid JSON.

Let's assume that these are the exact characters that you got in your response; i.e. the first character is a double-quote.   But a valid JSON object starts with a `{` character.  Not even whitespace is allowed according to strict reading of the syntax graph at https://json.org.

---

But what if that is actually a Java `String` literal representing the JSON?

In that case, the JSON is valid<sup>1</sup>.  And what is more, your code for the JSON is correct.  when I compile and run this, it works ... without throwing an exception.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response = "{\"SuccessData\":\"Data fetched successfully\",\"ErrorData\":\"\",\"AppData\":\"[{\\\"uniqe_id\\\":{\\\"appId\\\":4,\\\"agentId\\\":1,\\\"isActive\\\":1\\\"},\\\"pid\\\":2223,\\\"appName\\\":ACMP\\\"},{\\\"uniqe_id\\\":{\\\"appId\\\":5,\\\"agentId\\\":1,\\\"isActive\\\":1\\\"},\\\"pid\\\":2225,\\\"appName\\\":ICMP\\\"}]\"}";
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    }
}
```

Ergo, if you are getting a `JSONException` then the input is not a Java `String` literal.

---

<sup>1 - I wouldn't say it was correct.  The `AppData` attribute has a value that is a string not a JSON object.  But that string is a JSON serialization.  This is technically valid, but it is a poor design choice.</sup>

Comment: Yes, it is poor design, Also i resolved this issue by using Jackson ObjectMapper.

Comment: I think you did something more than (just) using ObjectMapper to fix the problem.  You should explain what you actually did in detail in a self-answer.

Comment: I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried with the following solution and it is working,

        import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

        private JSONObject deserializeResponse(String response) {
           logger.info("Parsing Serialized response object to JSON object");
           JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           try {
               responseJson = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), 
JSONObject.class);
           } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return responseJson;
        }
```

Comment: This isn't the complete answer.  You must have fixed something else as well.  The example input you gave won't work with this code either.

Comment: I've added the deseralize function. Nothing else to show more.

Comment: OK, so look at my Answer, copy the code to a file, compile and run it (with the json.org JAR) and please explain tell me if it works for you (like it works for me).  Then explain the difference between that and what you were actually doing that didn't work.