# How to convert JSOn in the form of a String to List<String> in Java

Tags: java, string, list

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> stringIds = mapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
```

where result = {
    "stringids": [
        "abc",
        "xyz"
    ]
}

So for Input `{
    "stringids": [
        "abc",
        "xyz"
    ]
}`, I want the result to be a list of strings abc, xyz

Getting this exception when trying above code:-

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token`

Comment: "{"abc", "xyz"}" is not valid JSON. Do you mean "["abc", "xyz"]"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java

Comment: Sweeper, I have corrected the JSON format here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you can't use a JSON library to deserialize broken JSON.

The correct way to represent a collection in JSON is `["abc", "def"]` not `{"abd", "def"}`.