# Is it possible to work with json type in java spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, json

Is it possible to work with json type as in javascript without generating JSONOject in java spring boot? Is it possible to work with the { } format without creating a JSONObject?

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. The Java syntax does not support JSON. So no, we cannot use JSON to declare objects in Java. We can, however, convert a `String` that contains a JSON-String into a `JSONObject`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java) from [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412/dogbane) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a JSONObject? It sounds like you want the format of JSON data and the JSON file extension without... using JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". The Java Syntax does not support JSON. Therefore, we cannot use JSON to declare any object in Java like

```
MyAwesomeObject object = { "name": "foo", "age": 42 };
```

We can, however, convert a `String` that contains a JSON-string into a `JSONObject`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java) by [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412/dogbane) for details.

If we use, for example, [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), we can convert a `String` to an object through jackson's [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```
final String json = "{ \"name\": \"foo\", \"age\": 42 }";
try {
    MyAwesomeObject object = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyAwesomeObject.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

For more details on jackson, I recommend reading [this tutorial from `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Comment: You can use JSON in Java with the help of one of several libraries, FWIW. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java