# Is there a way to tell GSON to parse strings with type names at beginning?

Tags: json, jersey, gson

from Jersey a classic JSON output of List looks like:

```
{"SubtaskType":{"id":"4","name":"mozaika","metric":"m2","code":"104"}}
```

But GSON will say it's not a JSON array and experimentally, it accepts:

```
{"id":"4","name":"mozaika","metric":"m2","code":"104"} for single SubtaskType.
```

I tested it with JSON validator and it seems that both forms are acceptable.

GSON's output of List looks like:

```
[{"name":"aa","metric":"m2","id":1,"code":200},{"name":"bb","metric":"m","id":2,"code":300}]
```

Is there a way to configure GSON to parse/generate the longer form (with type name)?

**Edit:**

This is the structure (added for change/discussion):

```
public class SubtaskType {
private int id;
private String name;
private String metric;
private int code;

//getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is based on the original version of the question.

> from Jersey a classic JSON output of List looks like:

```
{"SubtaskType":{"id":"4","name":"mozaika","metric":"m2","code":"104"}}
```

Really?  That's not a JSON array, i.e., list.  It's an object with one element named "SubtaskType", for which the element's value is an object with four elements.  There is no list.

Is that just what a list with a single component comes out like?  Does a list with two components come out like

```
{"SubtaskType":[{"id":"4","name":"mozaika","metric":"m2","code":"104"},{"name":"bb","metric":"m","id":2,"code":300}}
```

If this is the case, and you must receive such poorly-generated* JSON, and you must use Gson, then you'll have to implement custom deserialization processing to handle the situation where it's sometimes a list and it's sometimes an object.  This is an all-too-often occurring problem. Gson unfortunately does not yet have a simple configuration available to handle this often-occurring problem.  I posted an example of such custom deserialization processing in response to the question at [Parsing JSON with GSON, object sometimes contains list sometimes contains object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223023)

* Just because it's valid JSON, doesn't mean it's not crap.  An API should generate consistently-structured JSON.  Anything less is crap.

> GSON's output of List looks like:

```
[{"name":"aa","metric":"m2","id":1,"code":200},{"name":"bb","metric":"m","id":2,"code":300}]
```

Good.  That's what a list in JSON is supposed to look like.

> Is there a way to configure GSON to parse/generate the longer form (with type name)?

Yes.  The specific solution depends on what your Java data structure currently looks like, and whether you're able to change the structure to match the desired JSON.  If you cannot change the Java data structure accordingly, then you must custom process serialization/deserialization.  Post the Java data structure you'd like to use, and indicate whether it can be changed.

Also, post an exact example of the "longer form" JSON you want to generate that represents a list with at least two components.  You have not done this, yet.  So, it leaves me guessing about what you really want to do.

It does seem pretty clear that you want polymorphic type handling in whatever the ultimate solution is.  This will require custom deserialization processing, if using Gson.

Regarding any question on polymorphic deserialization, please note that the issue was discussed a few times on StackOverflow.com already. I posted a link to four different such questions and answers (some with code examples) at [Can I instantiate a superclass and have a particular subclass be instantiated based on the parameters supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424848/can-i-instantiate-a-superclass-and-have-a-particular-subclass-be-instantiated-bas/6426046#6426046).

For polymorphic serialization, not only will it likely be necessary to implement custom serialization to generate the desired type element, but convincing Gson to serialize all of the fields from polymorphic types also requires custom processing.  See [Serializing List of Interfaces GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952595) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such elaborate answer. As this needs to be ready tomorrow, we handled it simply by using GSON on the server side as well (which, as you pointed out, generates consistently structured output). However the guess on polymorphic de/serialization was wrong, I understand that issue and tried to avoid stumbling upon it. Anyway I will edit the post and add the structure and ask for the help with changing it, as you mentioned.