# Serializing and deserializing an ArrayList of interfaces

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization, gson

I have an interface, `Item`. The objects `Product` and `Category` implement `Item`. I have an `ArrayList<Item>` I need to serialize and deserialize. I tried using Gson, but it does not support serilization and deserialization of interfaces. What could I do? (maybe with Gson)

Comment: Tried this: http://pastebin.com/sFQbTN3c , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a serializer for the classes.

I used Gson. What I did was create a JSONValueSerializer class and interface IJSONValueSerializer (with one method toJsonString()). I then implemented JsonSerializer on the JSONValueSerializer class created.

Now from there all I had to do was implement the interface on any class I wanted to serialize and I had a common serializer for similar classes. So in your case you could implement this class on Item and the serializer will tell it how to serialize Product and Category when registered by the GsonBuilder.

```
private class JSONValueSerializer implements JsonSerializer<IJSONValueSerializer> {
  public JsonElement serialize(IJSONValueSerializer src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toJsonString());
  }
}
```

Then create the GsonBuilder and register any classes that are going to be serialized.

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new JSONValueSerializer());
gson.create().toJson(someObjectContainingMyClass);
```

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Comment: I don't get it. My `Product` has got a String, an int, and a Category, and my Categories have a String and an int. Could you provide a code sample that does that?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize to json?

Comment: I just tried `Gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>(){}.getType());`, which doesn't work. I don't know what you mean I should do in the serialize method.

Comment: Ah I see now. Check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952595/serializing-list-of-interfaces-gson

Comment: By the way, what should implement the IJSONValueSerializer, the `Item` or the `Product` and `Category`?

Comment: I was able to get it to work without the serializer and just specifying the type token as a List<Product> vs List<Item>. http://pastebin.com/M9tAVcSP