# Unknown crash report on Android Developer Console: InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, crash

I am currently getting a couple of unknown crash reports on the android developer console. They are quite inexpressive. Its an InvocationTargetException, but I have no clue where it is coming from. Maybe some framework that I am using which is using reflections?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Does anyone have an idea about this or maybe has the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Common libraries which we use mostly that are using reflection are

1.Gson

2.Retrofit

Comment: Yes correct, I use them both. Is that a common problem with these libraries?

Comment: There are lot of reasons behind that issue. Ex look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873887/issue-with-parse-json-to-java-object-using-gson

Comment: search for **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)** to get more info

Comment: I know that there are many possible causes. My problem is the incomplete stacktrace in the android developer console. I thought somebody might have the same problem.

Comment: That's why I told you to search the issue in Google to get possible traces