# Custom gson serialization for an abstract class

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Maybe I'm running in the wrong direction, but I have a list of elements which I want to read.

I have an abstract base class let's call it `Person`:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

Now I have two possible implementations:

```
public class Hunter implements Person {
    public int skill;
    // and some more stuff
}

public class Zombie implements Person {
    public int uglyness;
    // and some more stuff
}
```

Now I have this example JSON:

```
[
  {"id":1, "type":"zombie", "name":"Ugly Tom", "uglyness":42},
  {"id":2, "type":"hunter", "name":"Shoot in leg Joe", "skill":0}
]
```

How can I read this JSON as `List<Person>`?

I'm playing for a while with `TypeAdapterFactory` and tried to use a class called [`CustomizedTypeAdapterFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272452/995926) since my real structure is a little more complex as the funny example above.

I ended in that I want to delegate the serialization with this call:

```
return gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, resultType);
```

However I have no idea how I can create at runtime that `TypeToken<T>` which is required for this call. Any ideas?

Comment: This question looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000163/using-gson-and-abstract-classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I read this JSON as List?

One possibility would be to create a custom deserializer that acts like a factory.

The first step would be to define this deserializer

```
class PersonJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public Person deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String type = json.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
        switch(type) {
            case "zombie":
                return context.deserialize(json, Zombie.class);
            case "hunter":
                return context.deserialize(json, Hunter.class);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Neither zombie or hunter");
        }
    }
}
```

It fetches the value associated with the key "type" and choose the proper type to deserialize the object you're currently reading.

Then, you need to plug this deserializer within the parser.

```
public class GsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[\n" +
                "  {\"id\":1, \"type\":\"zombie\", \"name\":\"Ugly Tom\", \"uglyness\":42},\n" +
                "  {\"id\":2, \"type\":\"hunter\", \"name\":\"Shoot in leg Joe\", \"skill\":0}\n" +
                "]";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new PersonJsonDeserializer()).create();

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType();

        List<Person> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        for(Person p : list) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Running it with your example, I get:

```
Zombie{id=1; name=Ugly Tom; uglyness=42}
Hunter{id=2; name=Shoot in leg Joe; skill=0}
```

If the value of the type already corresponds to the class name, you might want to use `Class.forName` also:

```
class PersonJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public Person deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String className = json.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
        className = Character.toUpperCase(className.charAt(0)) + className.substring(1);
        try {
            return context.deserialize(json, Class.forName(className));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```