# How to use Gson to deserialize a Json with polymorphic sub object

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have problem when I design a Class to serialize and deserialize.

Here is the problem, I have a Class

```
class Thing {
  int a;
  String b;
  String type;
  Type typeinfo;
}
```

Basically the `Type` is the an abstract class like

```
abstract class Type {
 //nothing here
}
```

and I have a few implementation

```
class CarType extends Type {
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

and

```
class TruckType extends Type {
  list<Integer> listOfInt;
}
```

The `String type` is set to `"CarType"` or `"TruckType"` even others and I could know what's actual type of `typeinfo`

It's good to use Gson to serialize it but how to deserialize the json string?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of Json String

```
case1:
{
 "a" : 1,
 "b" : "aaa",
 "type": "car",
 "typeinfo": {
    "x" : 10,
    "y" : 100
  }
}

case2: 
{ 
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : "aaa",
 "type": "truck",
 "typeinfo": {
   "listOfInt" : [1, 2, 3]
 }
}
```

Just a quick mock up but I guess the idea should be clear, and the problem is I don't want to put the "type" into the typeinfo which supposed only the information.

Comment: Please, provide your JSON string as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Gson and Abstract Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000163/using-gson-and-abstract-classes)

Comment: I think you need a TypeAdapter, here is a good example: `http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/`