# GSON and InstanceCreator issue

Tags: java, reflection, deserialization, gson, type-safety

I have the following POJOs:

```
public interface Shape {
    public double calcArea();
    public double calcPerimeter();
}

public class Rectangle implement Shape {
    // Various properties of a rectangle
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
    // Various properties of a circle
}

public class ShapeHolder {
    private List<Shape> shapes;

    // other stuff
}
```

I have no problem getting GSON to serialize an instance of `ShapeHolder` to JSON. But when I try to deserialize a String of that JSON back into a `ShapeHolder` instance, I get errors:

```
String shapeHolderAsStr = getString();
ShapeHolder holder = gson.fromJson(shapeHodlderAsStr, ShapeHolder.class);
```

Throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface    
net.myapp.Shape. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$8.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:167)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
    ... rest of stack trace ommitted for brevity
```

So I looked [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator) and started implementing my own `ShapeInstanceCreator`:

```
public class ShapeInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Shape> {
    @Override
    public Shape createInstance(Type type) {
        // TODO: ???
        return null;
    }
}
```

But now I'm stuck: I'm only given a `java.lang.reflect.Type`, but I really need a `java.lang.Object` so I can write code like:

```
public class ShapeInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Shape> {
    @Override
    public Shape createInstance(Type type) {
        Object obj = convertTypeToObject(type);

        if(obj instanceof Rectangle) {
            Rectangle r = (Rectangle)obj;
            return r;
        } else {
            Circle c = (Circle)obj;
            return c;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What can I do?

### Update

Per @raffian's suggestion (the link he/she posted), I implemented an `InterfaceAdapter` **exactly** like the one in the link (I didn't change *anything*). Now I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: no 'type' member found in what was expected to be an interface wrapper
    at net.myapp.InterfaceAdapter.get(InterfaceAdapter.java:39)
    at net.myapp.InterfaceAdapter.deserialize(InterfaceAdapter.java:23)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19600090/1360888, it has a base class instead of a interface but it's like your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550086/791406)? Looks like a nice clean way to implement InstanceCreators.

I was using Gson too, but switched to [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) due to serialization issues. With Flex, you don't need instance creators, just make sure your objects have getters/setters for all fields based on JavaBean spec, and you're good to go:

```
 ShapeHolder sh = new ShapeHolder();
 sh.addShape(new Rectangle());
 sh.addShape(new Circle());
 JSONSerializer ser = new JSONSerializer();
 String json = ser.deepSerialize(sh);
 JSONDeserializer<ShapeHolder> der = new JSONDeserializer<ShapeHolder>();
 ShapeHolder sh2 = der.deserialize(json);
```

Comment: Thanks @raffian (+1) - I created an `InterfaceAdapter` like the example shows in the link you posted. I then registered it as a type adaptor with the `GsonBuilder` (again like the example shows). Now I'm getting a new error (please see my updated question). Any ideas as to what's going on now? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't, apologies, this is why I switched to flex, to avoid all this crap! :-) Is there any constraint forcing you to use Gson?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - I went to bed and just gave FlexJSON a whirl. What a treat! Imagine that: serialization/deserialization that "just works" right out of the box! You've definitely converted me - thanks!

Comment: exactly, it just works, welcome to the dark side :-)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE that [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) is adding class name as part of json like below serialize time.

```
{
    "HTTPStatus": "OK",
    "class": "com.XXX.YYY.HTTPViewResponse",
    "code": null,
    "outputContext": {
        "class": "com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.OutputSuccessContext",
        "eligible": true
    }
}
```

So JSON will be cumber some; but you don't need write `InstanceCreator` which is required in GSON.