# Android array to Sharedpreferences with Gson

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences, flexjson

I need to create an array of the last 5 call dates.

I know that I have to save the date on the array but I don't know how to reorder the other records to keep this last call date the 1st record. And always maintain only 5 records

The Goal is to save that last call string and add to the array, after that I reorder to and maintain only the 5 records, after that I use FlexJson to make a string and save on sharedpreferences. Anyone have this full process?

**Here what I'm doing but is throwing errors everywhere:**

**SAVE**

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDateTimeString = df.format(calendar.getTime());

List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONSerializer ser = new JSONSerializer();
textList.add(currentDateTimeString);

String jsonText = ser.deepSerialize(textList);

editor.putString("lastCall", jsonText);
editor.commit();
```

**READ:**

```
String lastCall = callLogPreferences.getString("lastCall", null);
JSONDeserializer<List<String>> der = new JSONDeserializer<>();
List<String> textList = der.deserialize(lastCall);
```

I'm using FlexJson: [GSON and InstanceCreator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447897/gson-and-instancecreator-issue/20448172#20448172)

It's not converting from string to Array List

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705860/saving-serializable-objects-list-into-sharedpreferences/16607928#16607928

Comment: Hi @GuilhE if you check the link on my question you will see that FlexJson don't require a InstanceCreator, I used GSON but it was throwing that error.

Comment: I find Gson more straightforward. Can you post you Gson serialize code and error?

Comment: Hi @GuilhE I don't have it, I've seen in some stackoverflow topic. Can you show me an answer how to make a array list into string and then the string to array list with GSON? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let me give you an advise - if you have 3 question create 3 topics, not one with all the questions. Based on the question title: **Android array to sharedpreferences** I'll give an answer just to this issue.

So from your question you want to store a `List<String>` myList inside `SharedPreferences`. To do so I advise you to use `Gson` because it's simple. The main idea it's to serialize your `List` to a `String` in `json` and then store that `String`:

Since you are using primitive types you don't need to specify a [TypeToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705860/saving-serializable-objects-list-into-sharedpreferences/16607928#16607928) so you just need to:

```
public static final MY_LIST = "my_list";

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(MY_LIST, new Gson().toJson(myList));
editor.commit();
```

And it's stored. To retrieve the list just do the opposite:

```
myList = new Gson().fromJson(prefs.getString(MY_LIST, null), List<String>);
```

And that's it!
Hope it helped.

ps: `SharedPreferences` it's used to store values that can be accessed in other `Classes`/`Activities`/etc.. or to persist information between app restarts. You don't need this to accomplish what you want: Create a list with 5 ordered strings.

**EDIT:** this [lib](https://github.com/GuilhE/android-utils-lib) may save you some time with the serialization ;)

Comment: Hi, so I need to .add the strings to that myList right? ( myList.add("x"); )

Comment: Yes, the code I gave you here it's just an example on how to store a List inside SharedPreferences. If the List has elements, ordered or not, or it's empty it's up to you.

Comment: dateList = new Gson().fromJson(callLogPreferences.getString("lastCall", null), new TypeToken<List<String>>(){                  --->  make the job on your last code tip! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `ArrayList` with a custom `Comparator` as seen here: [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Then, sort the `ArrayList` accordingly.

Comment: No sorry, the above link is more than sufficient for what I believe you are asking. I am not here to do your job :). However if you feel my answer has not been sufficient, please extend details or clarify for me and I will do my best to reply with additional information/correct what I have said.

Comment: Hi there, okay no problem, I'm a noob and your answer is like nothing to me :( sorry. If you cannot make a better example I understand

Comment: From what I understand you are writing the `JSON` above to `sharedPreferences`, then attempting to retrieve the `JSON` data back. Correct?

Comment: Yes, some guy told me that I need to convert the array to string with json, save with sharedpreferences and then convert the json string into array again to read the data and place on that expandable listview. But it's not working :( I've the 3 topics about what is not working