# Convert JSON string to JMS Message

Tags: java, json, jms, gson

I have a scenario where I have to save the JMS messages on disk. I write the messages in JSON format using the Gson library as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(message);
bufferedWriter.write(json);
```

But when I try to read this message,

```
Message m = gson.fromJson(json, Message.class);
System.out.println(m.getJMSType());
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface javax.jms.Message. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:210)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700)
```

How do I read a JMS message from Json string?

Answer (score 0):

`Message` is an interface. Gson can't initialize it. If the actual implementation class is known/under your control - you may replace  deserialization with something like

```
Message m = gson.fromJson(json, ActiveMQBlobMessage.class);
```

Otherwise, if you need interface - you may look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795349/how-to-serialize-a-class-with-an-interface/9550086#9550086) post.