# Deserializing a List<MyInterface> that contains a List<MyOtherInterface> using Gson

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson, deserialization

I had huge problems deserializing a `List<IWorkout>`, since it would throw

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MY PACKAGE}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface MY INTERFACE. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`

But I solved it by deserializing it to a `List<Workout>` (which implements the interface IWorkout), and then adding it to a `List<IWorkout>`.

Code example of my solution :

```
public ArrayList <IWorkout> loadUserWorkoutList(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type workoutListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Workout>>(){}.getType();

    List <Workout> workoutList = gson.fromJson(loadWorkoutDataFromSharedPreferences(), workoutListType);

    if (workoutList == null){
        workoutList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    ArrayList<IWorkout> iWorkoutList = new ArrayList<>(workoutList);

    return iWorkoutList;
}
```

But the problem now is that the Workout contains another `List<IExercise>` which I can't (or at least can't figure out how to) perform this "trick" on. The entire IWorkout list is serialized like this :

```
private String workoutListToJsonString(List<IWorkout> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String jsonString = gson.toJson(list);

    return jsonString;
}
```

and it throws the same error as before when I try to deserialize it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

I've tried using the adapter provided by [Narthi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795349/how-to-serialize-a-class-with-an-interface/9550086#9550086%20%22), but to no success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't serialize interfaces.

Comment: Hence the workaround method loadUserWorkoutList(), I was wondering if there is any way to do the same thing to a list which contains another List<Interface>